# Chaincode should only be installed on endorsing peer nodes?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

According to hyperledger fabric documentation, the chaincode should only be deployed in endorsing peers, and it says still the non endorsing peers can validate and update the ledger. Now I am bit confused if non endorsing peers don't have a chaincode, how can they generate R/W sets. How the non endorsing peers will be able to create new state for the asset, if they aren't aware of the logic (chaincode) behind it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/txflow.html#, you'll find a section that states:

*The blocks of transactions are “delivered” to all peers on the channel. The transactions within the block are validated to ensure endorsement policy is fulfilled and to ensure that there have been no changes to ledger state for read set variables since the read set was generated by the transaction execution. Transactions in the block are tagged as being valid or invalid.*

A block is an ordered set of transactions and transactions include the state transitions in the form of read/write sets.  The output of endorsement is actually the read/write set and these are what are ordered and delivered to all peers in the channel.

In order to validate a transaction, a peer needs to check the following:

- Is the transaction well-formed
- Was the endorsement policy met (the
  endorsement policy is distributed to all peers in a channel when
  chaincode is instantiated even if the peer does not have the
  chaincode bytes)
- MVCC check

In order to do the above, peers do not need to execute the chaincode itself.

Comment: ok.. So it means only the endorsing peers execute the chain code and the all the peers just do the validations related to transaction structure, double spend etc. but not the chaincode validation ?

Comment: they validate the read write sets generated and make sure that the transaction were properly endorsed